# How to create a search view that displays selected columns

Tags: profile, advanced-search

I have never managed to get this function to work properly so here goes.

I have created  profile with some custom fields (individual) and selected the option Search Views, Standalone Form or Directory

I then go to advanced search and select the group I want to view; I also select views for display contacts and select the profile I want.

When I press search I get the correct list of people but not the fields that I want to see. I just get display name.

I am on 5.3.2 although i've never been able to get it to work tbh

Any tips!?
Thanks
Caroline

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Caroline,

You need to enable additional setting for the fields you want to display them as a column. You can do this now by editing the fields you want to show them as a column and do the following

1. Select 'Expose Publicly' from visibility
2. Check 'Results Column?'

[image]

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: That's excellent! Thanks. Can I check what does "expose publicly" mean in this case. Who can see this data. I want it so that only people who are able to access civicrm data can see it. Thanks

Comment: So can we mark this as Answered so that it will be helpful for other who will hit the same issue?

Comment: Those options means "Is this field hidden from public search ('User and User Admin Only'), or is it visible to the public and potentially searchable in the Profile Search form ('Expose Publicly' or 'Expose Publicly and for Listings')? ('User and User Admin Only') fields can still be used for Edit and Create mode.

When visibility is 'Expose Publicly and for Listings', users can also click the field value when viewing a contact in order to locate other contacts with the same value(s) (i.e. other contacts who live in Poland)."

Comment: Hi Pradeep - sorry I don’t quite understand your extra piece of information. Are you saying that this field could be visible to the public (ie people who do not have a user role which allows them access to the Civicrm database. I definitely do not want members of the public to see the contents of this field

Comment: This fields will only be accessible if the anonymous user have access to search contact using profile. Else they won't be able to access this field.

Comment: HI Pradeep how would the anonymous user be given this permission. I am on drupal. Would it be through the perople/permissions? I have had a look and the following permission options are avilable there: 1. CiviCRM: profile listings and forms 2. CiviCRM: profile listings 3. CiviCRM: profile create 4. CiviCRM: profile edit 5. CiviCRM: profile view   Sorry to keep asking I'm keen to finally crack this and then mark the answer with a tick! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't give anonymous user permission for 1. CiviCRM: profile listings and forms 2. CiviCRM: profile listings

Comment: Thanks a lot Pradeep. Thats really helpful :)